# CSS style flashes and vanishes soon on JSF page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have primeface p:panel on jsf file. I apply background color with the following style on the template page (anasayfa.xhtml).

```
<h:head>
    <style type="text/css">
.bos{background-color:red;}
</style>
</h:head>
```

My Jsf Page with viewscoped backing bean:

```
<ui:composition template="/anasayfa.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="ortaAlan">
...

<p:panel styleClass="bos">
...
</p:panel>


</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

When I load page background color is seen for very shortly, then becomes transparent. CTRL+F5 has the same effect.

What is wrong here?
Thanks for helps in advance

[image: Panel's selector and computed style]

---

jsf page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<ui:composition template="/anasayfa.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="ortaAlan">
    <p:panel id="rezerveleriniz">
            <h:outputText value="#{rezervasyonBean.bugun.time}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
            </h:outputText> : Rezervasyon Saatleri <br/>


    <ui:repeat var="r" value="#{rezervasyonBean.kullaniciRezervasyonSaatleri}">
    #{r.saatAraligi}<br/>
    </ui:repeat>

    </p:panel>

        <h:form id="aaa">


<p:panel>
<p:panel style="float:left;">
            <h:panelGrid columns="1">
            <ui:repeat var="rs" value="#{rezervasyonBean.rezervasyonSaatleriListesi}">

**// !!!!!!!!!!!! Problem is here !!!!!!!!**

                <p:panel styleClass="#{rezervasyonBean.isRezervasyonOnThisDay(rs) ? 'dolu' : 'bos' }">
                    #{rs.saatAraligi}
                    <h:commandButton action="#{rezervasyonBean.sec(rs,'1')}" value="+" update=":rezerveleriniz" disabled="#{rezervasyonBean.isRezervasyonOnThisDay(rs)}" />
                </p:panel>
            </ui:repeat>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:commandButton action="#{rezervasyonBean.kaydet()}" value="Kaydet" />
</p:panel>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <title>Görev Takip Sistemi</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-widget,.ui-widget .ui-widget {
            font-size: 12px !important;
            font-family:Arial;
        }

.bos{
background-color:red;
}
.dolu{
background-color:yellow;
}

        #topPanel {z-index:2 !important; }
        #topPanel div{overflow:visible;}

        .colStyle_panelGridForGorev{
            width:225px;
        }
        .colStyle_panelGridForProfil{
            width:100px;
        }
    </style>

</h:head>
<body>  


    <p:growl for="growlForAnasayfa" showDetail="true" life="3000" autoUpdate="true"/>

    <h:form>
        <p:idleMonitor timeout="900000">  
            <p:ajax event="idle" listener="#{anasayfaBean.indirectLogout}"/>  
        </p:idleMonitor>  
    </h:form>

    <p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();" />  

    <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Status"   
            draggable="false" closable="false">  
        <p:graphicImage value="/images/statusBar.gif" />  
    </p:dialog> 

    <p:layout fullPage="true">

        <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="50"  id="topPanel" style="border:0px">
            <h:form id="formAnaSayfaToolbar">
                <p:toolbar>
                    <p:toolbarGroup align="left">
                        <p:commandButton type="submit" value="#{anasayfaBean.kullanici.kullaniciAdi} #{anasayfaBean.kullanici.kullaniciSoyadi}" 
                            style="margin-left:200px;" action="/profil.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" ajax="false"/>
                        <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Gruplarım" 
                            action="/kullanici/gruplarim.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" ajax="false" rendered="#{!anasayfaBean.daireBaskani}"/>
                        <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Görevlerim" 
                            action="/gorevListele.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" ajax="false" rendered="#{!anasayfaBean.daireBaskani}"/>

                        <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Kullanıcı İşlemleri" 
                            action="/daireBaskani/kullanici.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" ajax="false" rendered="#{anasayfaBean.daireBaskani}"/>
                        <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Grup İşlemleri" 
                            action="/daireBaskani/grup.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" ajax="false" rendered="#{anasayfaBean.daireBaskani}"/>

                        <p:menuButton value="Görev İşlemleri" rendered="#{anasayfaBean.daireBaskani}">
                            <p:menuitem value="Yeni Görev Ekle" url="/daireBaskani/gorevEkle.btk" />  
                            <p:menuitem value="Gorevleri Listele" url="/gorevListele.btk" />  
                        </p:menuButton>

                        <p:menuButton value="Admin Paneli" rendered="#{anasayfaBean.admin}"> 
                            <p:menuitem value="Birim İşlemleri" url="/admin/birim.btk" />  
                            <p:menuitem value="Ünvan İşlemleri" url="/admin/unvan.btk" />  
                        </p:menuButton>

                    </p:toolbarGroup>
                    <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                        <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Çıkış" icon="ui-icon-close" 
                            action="#{anasayfaBean.logout}" ajax="false"  style="margin-right:200px;"/>
                    </p:toolbarGroup>
                </p:toolbar> 
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <ui:insert name="ortaAlan">
                <h:outputText value="Yukarıdaki menüden yapmak istediğiniz işlemi seçiniz." />
            </ui:insert>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="30" resizable="true" style="border-width:0px;">
            <h:form style="text-align:center; font-size:13px;">
                <h:outputText value="Bilişim Sistemleri Dairesi © 2012" />
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="200"  id="eastPanel" style="border:0px">
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="200"  id="westPanel" style="border:0px">
        </p:layoutUnit>

    </p:layout>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that really the minimum necessary code in order to reproduce the problem? I can't reproduce your problem when I copypaste the so far provided code into empty basic templates. Do you have any custom JS code in your page?

Comment: Only primefaces js libraries. I am posting full template and and jsf page as if I answer my own question since comment area is limited.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the rendered HTML? p:panel has `ui-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all` classes to begin with. `ui-widget-content` contains background-color information and could be overriding your implementation. Inspect it.

Comment: I did already. Html source of the panel is `<div id="aaa:j_idt36:0:j_idt37" class="ui-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all dolu">` and computed stype panel says background color is yellow as I expected. But yellow background only applied at the page load for very short time.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Which browser(s) did you try? The code snippet is by the way not exactly copy'n'paste'n'runnable. The bean is missing, the ui:repeat remains empty, etc. I'd have to stub the bean to keep some EL expressions happy. Please come up with the smallest possible but complete and copy'n'paste'n'runnable Facelets file which demonstrates the exact problem. If the backing bean is not necessary in order to reproduce the problem, then just omit it, but please remove/fix the EL expressions so that it's *really* copy'n'paste'n'runnable without the need for any changes.